# Configure error with Qt 5.8 and SQL libraries

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.8

While building Qt 5.7, I used to call the following command line:

> C:\SDK\Qt\src\configure -commercial -confirm-license
> -debug-and-release -force-debug-info -ltcg -static -angle -nomake examples -nomake tests **-qt-sql-odbc -qt-sql-sqlite** -qt-zlib -D
> Z_PREFIX -skip qt3d -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtandroidextras -skip
> qtpurchasing -skip qttools -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtconnectivity -skip
> qtdatavis3d -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtdoc -skip qtgamepad -skip
> qtgraphicaleffects -skip qtimageformats -skip qtlocation -skip
> qtmacextras -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtquickcontrols2 -skip qtsensors
> -skip qtserialport -skip qtsvg -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtwinextras -skip qtx11extras -skip qtxmlpatterns -prefix C:\SDK\Qt\x64

However, with Qt 5.8, this command line fails with the following error message:

> ERROR: Invalid value given for boolean command line option 'sql-odbc'.
>
> ERROR: Invalid value given for boolean command line option 'sql-sqlite'.

According to the [Qt 5.8 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html), my command line seems just fine.

What am I supposed to do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812121/qt-lite-and-configuration-changes-in-qt-5-8/41962051#41962051

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently the parameters have been renamed. and the documentation is not up to date.

The correct command line is:

> C:\SDK\Qt\src\configure -commercial -confirm-license
>   -debug-and-release -force-debug-info -ltcg -static -angle -nomake examples -nomake tests **-sql-odbc -sql-sqlite** -qt-zlib -D Z_PREFIX
>   -skip qt3d -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtandroidextras -skip qtpurchasing -skip qttools -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtdoc -skip qtgamepad -skip qtgraphicaleffects -skip qtimageformats -skip qtlocation -skip
>   qtmacextras -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtquickcontrols2 -skip qtsensors
>   -skip qtserialport -skip qtsvg -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtwinextras -skip qtx11extras -skip qtxmlpatterns -prefix C:\SDK\Qt\x64

It looks like we should now use `-sql<driver>` instead of `-qt-sql<driver>`.