# QT Lite for Android application development

Tags: android, ios, qt, qt5.8, qt-lite

I am going through QT Lite documentation from past few hours, not finding any helpful documentation regarding how to use QT Lite. I want to use QT Lite for Android and iOS application development. Already read following links

1. [QT Lite Overview](https://www.qt.io/event/qt-lite-overview/)
2. [QT Lite and Configuration changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812121/qt-lite-and-configuration-changes-in-qt-5-8)`
3. [QT Lite project information](https://www.qt.io/qt-news/qt-company-introduces-major-expansion-development-framework-support-global-demand-connected-devices/)
4. [QT Lite as lightweight developer framwork](https://soylentnews.org/article.pl?sid=16/10/09/0644208)

and many more links available on internet giving basic information about the QT Lite framework, from these links

> Qt 5.8 will include IoT-oriented “Qt Lite” technology that enables
>   fine-grained configuration and supports small-footprint IoT gizmos
>   without OpenGL. The Qt Company announced a Qt Lite project that aims
>   to extend the Qt development framework to smaller footprint Internet
>   of Things devices with as little as 16MB RAM and flash. The Qt Lite
>   technology will initially appear in Qt 5.8, including a more flexible
>   configuration system for the cross-platform development framework, as
>   well as a new 2D renderer for devices that can’t run OpenGL. Qt Lite
>   also provides a more accessible, lightweight set of development tools.

From above links getting feel that QT lite can be used for Devices with less RAM(< 16MB), Devices that require programs with low memory footprint and/or IoT kind of devices.

My Question is Can we use QT Lite for Android and iOS application development? If yes, where can i get steps to port and build existing QT 5.8 project to QT Lite project. Reference link will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
My Question is Can we use QT Lite for Android and iOS application development?
```

Shortly, Yes. But Qt Lite it is your own build of Qt (from 5.8). You simply disable some unimportant for you features and in result you get smaller qt libs.

Also seems like it is dublicated question to this: [Qt Lite and configuration changes in Qt 5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812121/qt-lite-and-configuration-changes-in-qt-5-8)